# How do I access the hidden mini game in Call of Duty: Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I've heard there is a hidden mini game that can be accessed from the main menu in black ops. Something about finding a terminal and entering a code.

Does anyone have instructions on how to get to the terminal and what code to put in?

Comment: Youtube video showing the mini game Dead Ops Arcade:
http://www.youtube.com/user/WoodysGamertag#p/u/4/EIiZop7kcQI

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you are referring to [Dead Ops Arcade](http://www.computerandvideogames.com/article.php?id=274563).  Here's an explanation I found of how to access it.

> Accessing it isn't just a matter of
>   finishing the game. You've got to bust
>   your way out of the main menu screen,
>   then work your way around to a
>   terminal and type in the correct
>   commands to boot the game.
>
> While in the menu look down (using the
>   right analogue stick, presumably) at
>   your hands and mash the triggers to
>   wriggle your hands until they come
>   free.
>
> You'll stand up and be given the
>   freedom to roam. Go to the terminal,
>   access it and enter CD, then DOA. Bam
>   - giant machine guns, flame throwers and rocket-firing bats are yours for
>   the shooting.

Comment: So do you need to finish the game before this becomes available or is it available from the start?

Comment: You can do this mini-game from the very beginning, no need to beat the game to access this or the Zork game.

Comment: I recently came across an option to play Dead Ops Arcade from the Zombie menu. It is selectable as a level/map. I found this an easy way to start a multiplayer game.

Answer (score 3):

Yea just hit both yours triggers or r2 and l2 buttons at the same time, go to the computer behind the chair you are sitting in, then type in `doa` on it. There's a tutorial here:
http://www.Youtube.com/cjonduty

Answer (score 2):

In the PC version, you have to hold the SPACE button in the main menu to free yourself and walk around. Then you can go to terminal and explore what it has to offer.

One thing I found really funny was the option to sit down - why should one give in willingly to be tied and beaten up? But that is necessary to access the main menu again.

Answer (score 1):

Press R2 and L2 at the same time while looking at your hands below (you don't have to look at your hands but it adds to the affect of you breaking out of the chair), search for the computer behind where you were sitting, and type the code: DOA (for a fighting game) or the code: Zork (to play the actual game [Zork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zork))

Thanks to gunktv belgium