# What is the meaning of the Black Ops "Ascension" numbers

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

During the intro of Call of Duty Black Ops one of the cut scenes has a lady read "Ascension 7-15-1-2-19-7-25-6-13-6-7-15-14-0" into a microphone.

Is this relevant to anything other than the single player campaign? (Which I haven't played through yet)

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10664/how-do-i-trigger-the-cinematic-at-the-beginning-of-black-ops

Comment: 15k views! For this? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no known relevance to anything other than the single player campaign.

Since you haven't played through the single player campaign, I won't give it away, but you can look up the meaning of the numbers here on the [Call of Duty Wikia](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Jhudson). Also, you can use the terminal in the menu (Accessed by tips in this question: [How do I access the hidden mini game in Call of Duty: Black Ops?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10491/hidden-mini-game-in-call-of-duty-black-ops)) to DECODE the numeric messages if you'd like to do it alone.

Answer (score 2):

Ascension is the name of the first zombie map from the new map pack :D

http://www.callofduty.com/BLACKOPS/DLC

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_station

Comment: Interesting background info, plus the popular culture reference to black ops.

Answer (score 1):

The newest zombie map in DLC is called Ascension.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't scare the zombies off with any of these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Ascension is the new Nazi zombie map on the new map-pack which will be released on the 2nd of February for Xbox. There hasn't been an announced release date yet for PS3 or PC.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new map pack coming out which includes a new zombie map called "Ascension". The release date for the PS3 and PC is one month after the 360 release, the 2nd of February.

Answer (score 1):

Ascension is the name of the new zombie map that will be a part of the "First Strike" DLC coming February 1, 2011. It will be released on Xbox Live before other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, we've been working on this over at my site and have figured out a bunch of stuff but are still putting pieces together all the time. Everything is more relevant than anyone would think and it's been fun figuring it out so far. Check out the article if you wanna see what we've got so far, new stuff all the time too!

http://bigdah.gamerkage.com/black-ops-arcade-easter-egg-revealed.html

Comment: If there are things your site has discovered which are relevant to the question, you should write them here instead of redirecting to an external link in case your site goes down...which it seems to be now based on the fact that your link isn't working for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the code for the gun and where and how to kill JFK. Watch the rest of it: you hear Mason say after the fifth number "One" and after three more numbers "22.mm" (caliber of gun used to kill JFK). After five or six more, he says Texas (where he was shot) and then it stops the REAL footage of JFK before he died and zooms in to show Mason in the crowd. So basically, in the game's fiction, the US covered the real guy that killed JFK and the guy that was arrested didn't do it.